# How to get the last parameter in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm wondering how to obtain the last argument passed to a bash function, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello() {
    all=$@         # all arguments
    n=$#           # number of arguments
    first_arg=$1   # argument one
    last_arg= ???  # How to get the last argument?
}
```

How to set `$last_arg` to the value of the last argument passed to the function?

Comment: @GregHilston Does that excludes the last argument from the second variable?

Comment: Downvote beacuse you posted your whole shell script here. Why are the `sed` commands and other stuff interesting for us? Your example should look like this: http://pastebin.com/vyp0drSs  Do you was too lazy to make a simple example out of it? I don't understand why somebody should post something like this.

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, I posted the whole script so you can test its functionality, if needed. I'm trying to follow the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `…Complete` means `Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem` and means not post your whole shell script.

Comment: Good to hear that you are at least aware of the the `How to ask` page. You need to get a better feeling of what is important and what not.

Comment: I've edited it. Doesn't it look much more clean now?

Comment: It does, indeed. I was going to edit like this 

add_a(){
  var1=$1
  var2=$@ - first and last
  var3=last
} 

but it looks better that way, thank you

Comment: Moderators: if the question has been asked before and already has an answer, please include the link to the answer in your rejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `all` holds the `$@`, then the last argument is `${all[*]: -1}`